# Automatic Logout after 5 minutes of inactive in yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

May I know how to have function of automatic logout if users have inactive more than 5 minutes in yii2 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this configuration :

```
'user' => [
        'enableAutoLogin' => false,
        'authTimeout' => 300,
    ],
```

[authTimeout](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-user.html#$authTimeout-detail)

Comment: I used this code It logged out successfully.. but when clicked on any of the menu It gives error...Error
PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException
Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: It should get redirected to login page.. please see this que... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49672356/after-auto-logout-how-to-redirect-the-control-to-login-page-in-yii2

Comment: This will not redirect the user automatically after 300 seconds. 
what should I need to add if I want to redirect automatically after 300 seconds?
@InsaneSkull

Answer (score 0):

Your answer lies in configuration of "user" component in your config files.

Everything you need to know is in this documentation [Yii2 User Component](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-user.html), set authTimout property to 300 (that's in seconds) and your user should be logged out after 5 minutes of inactivity.

Comment: the thing you mention is working but the issue it is not redirecting automatically the login page, the user needs to reload or click on other module and then on it will redirect to the login.

Comment: If the user is inactive after 5 mins, the next action they perform will redirect to the login. I find this acceptable, rather than using javascript to keep reloading the page every 5 mins. That can be a negative user experience if the user is still active on the page...

Comment: He could have an ajax call that ping the server to see if the user is logged in or not, only if he's logged out it should reload/redirect to login page, otherwise do nothing. Not the best solution but an easy one to implement.

Answer (score 0):

In your component configuration you need to add config in user component like this

```
'components'=>[
        'user' => [
            'class'=>'yii\web\User',
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
            'loginUrl'=>['sign-in/login'],
            'enableAutoLogin' => false,
            'authTimeout'=>300,  //Number of second to Automatic Logout if inactive
            //this config is optional
            'identityCookie' => [
                'name' => '_backendUser', // unique for backend
                'path'=>'@backend/web'  // correct path for the backend app.
            ],
            'as afterLogin' => 'common\behaviors\LoginTimestampBehavior'
        ],
    ],
```

Comment: how to redirect the user automatically to the login page because in this if use is inactive for 300 seconds and then try to perform any action it will take the user to login.
it should be auto redirect to login after 300 seconds.

Comment: for that you have to trigger reload or redirect like `setTimeout(function() {
  location.reload();
}, 300000);`

Answer (score 0):

Besides of setting up the **main.php** I have three suggestion to handle this situation.

1. You should set you application in production mode ..
2. customize the site/error.php to check if user is guest and if not display the div with message like "Session expires" and a link to "site/login".
3. Alternatively, To redirect to login page when clicks on any link, define the access-control in a controller **behaviors** function and then you are done.