# after auto logout how to redirect the control to login page in yii2?

Tags: yii2

I am using below code to auto logout after some time interval

```
'session' => [
    'timeout' => 10,
],
'user' => [
    'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
    'enableAutoLogin' => false,
    'authTimeout' => 10,
],
```

It logged out successfully 
but did not redirect to login page 
how to do that?

Comment: [Will help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38227467/yii-2-redirecting-to-login-if-guest-visit-the-website) and [a gist](https://gist.github.com/r3verser/7cdaf9c3a4f2f631d1d1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **behaviors** for actions.

```
 public function behaviors()
 {
     return [
         'access' => [
             'class' => AccessControl::className(),
             'only' => ['index', 'logout','view','create','update','delete'],
             'rules' => [
                 [
                     'actions' => ['index', 'logout','view','create','update','delete'],
                     'allow' => true,
                     'roles' => ['@'],
                 ],
             ],
         ],
     ];
 }
```

So user is not logged in it will redirect to login url. You can also set login url

```
'session' => [
        'timeout' => 10,
      ],
'user' => [
      'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
      'enableAutoLogin' => false,
      'authTimeout' => 10,
      'loginUrl' => 'admin/default/login' // set your login path here
     ],
```

OR You can use **beforeAction** method to check that user is logged in or not and send user to login page.

```
 public function beforeAction($action){

        if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest){
            return $this->redirect(['site/login'])->send();  // login path
        }
    }
```

Comment: Error
PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException
Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Which method you are using

Comment: first one method

Comment: @Goli, First method is used to prevent unauthorized user to access your page. I think you have any different error , Show You full error line